# Using Group by with Order by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Why does this SQL query show syntax error:

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered) AS 'Total'
FROM orderdetails
GROUP BY orderNumber
ORDER BY quantityOrdered;
```

BUT 
the below query shows no syntax error and give the correct result:

```
SELECT orderNumber, SUM(quantityOrdered) AS 'Total'
FROM orderdetails
GROUP BY orderNumber
ORDER BY Total;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT od.orderNumber, SUM(od.quantityOrdered) AS Total
FROM orderdetails od
GROUP BY od.orderNumber
ORDER BY od.quantityOrdered;
```

Is referring to `quantityOrdered` in the `ORDER BY` clause.  However, `ORDER BY` can only operate *after* the data is aggregated.  Hence, each row has summarized multiple `quantityOrdered` for each row.  SQL doesn't know which one you mean -- and you get an error.

For instance, your data might be:

```
A     1
A     5
B     3
```

After the aggregation, it looks like:

```
A     6
B     3
```

There is no `quantityOrdered`, only `Total`.

To fix this, you can use the column alias or aggregation function:

```
ORDER BY SUM(od.quantityOrdered);
```

Comment: except this statement: "Hence, there are multiple quantityOrdered for each row" I got all.

Comment: @AK . . . I changed the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ORDER BY Total` to `ORDER BY SUM(quantityOrdered)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the result of the query has a column with the name `quantityOrdered`. The second column of the result is the result of the function `SUM` which is different from the original column `quantityOrdered`. That's why when you used an alias for that result `AS 'Total'` it worked.

Comment: Thanks ...... I noticed that there is no "quantityOrdered" column there is the alias. So It means that ORDER BY clause executed at last ....... after the query is processed and result table is created ?